# removing multiple elements from a list and keeping track of them

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to remove elements from an original list *tokens* which are at specified indices  *indices_to_remove* and also keep the record of the deleted records but the problem is that when I have two indices to remove and I remove the record from first index, the second record cannot be removed correctly. Any idea on how to address this?

```
deleted_records = []
tokens = ['hi', 'what', 'is', 'there']
indices_to_remove = [2,3]
for index in indices_to_remove: 
    deleted_tokens.append(tokens[index])
    del tokens[index]
```

Comment: @TomMcLean OP wants to retain the removed items as well. So, strictly speaking, this may not be a dup of that other question, no?

Comment: Are the indices always already sorted?

Comment: Does the order of `deleted_records` matter? Shall its order correspond to the order of `indices_to_remove`?

Comment: Yes we want the order to be same indices_to_remove

Comment: And the sortedness?

Comment: Check the `partition` function defined in the [`itertools` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes).

Comment: Yes you can assume index is sorted

Comment: @vkaul11 Are the indices always valid? That is, are they all positive integers less than the length of `tokens`?

Comment: Yes we can assume indices are always valid

Comment: Would be good to add those things to the question.

Answer (score 2):

Its generally not a good idea to modify a collection while iterating it.

So, the simplest way is to maintain two lists to gather the results like this

```
removed, retained = [], []
tokens = ['hi', 'what', 'is', 'there']
indices_to_remove = {2, 3} # Set for faster lookups

for idx, token in enumerate(tokens):
     selected_list = removed if idx in indices_to_remove else retained
     selected_list.append(token)

print(removed, retained)
```

Comment: slightly faster than mine: 112ms vs 135ms for 1M tokens and 1000 `indices_to_remove`.

Answer (score 2):

List comprehensions are *fast*.

```py
deleted = [tokens[i] for i in sorted(indices_to_remove)]
tokens = [e for i, e in enumerate(tokens) if i not in indices_to_remove]
```

But first, given some ambiguity in the question, and for the sake of performance, some assumptions:

1. `indices_to_remove` is a `set` (O(1) membership test).
2. The OP wants `deleted` to be in the same order as in the initial `tokens` list.
3. (Obviously) all indices are valid (`0 <= i < len(tokens)` for all `i`). If not, well, you'll get an `IndexError`.

#### Speed test

```py
import random
from math import isqrt

def gen(n):
    tokens = [f'x-{i}' for i in range(n)]
    indices_to_remove = set(random.sample(range(n), isqrt(n)))
    return tokens, indices_to_remove


# our initial solution
def f0(tokens, indices_to_remove):
    deleted = [e for i, e in enumerate(tokens) if i in indices_to_remove]
    tokens = [e for i, e in enumerate(tokens) if i not in indices_to_remove]
    return deleted, tokens


# improved version, based on a comment by @KellyBundy
def f1(tokens, indices_to_remove):
    deleted = [tokens[i] for i in sorted(indices_to_remove)]
    tokens = [e for i, e in enumerate(tokens) if i not in indices_to_remove]
    return deleted, tokens


# @thefourtheye version
def f4(tokens, indices_to_remove):
    removed, retained = [], []
    for idx, token in enumerate(tokens):
        selected_list = removed if idx in indices_to_remove else retained
        selected_list.append(token)
    return removed, retained


# modified Kelly_1 to comply with our assumptions
# the original is certainly even faster, but modifies
# tokens in place, so harder to benchmark
def Kelly_1(tokens, indices_to_remove):
    tokens = tokens.copy()
    indices_to_remove = sorted(indices_to_remove)
    return [*map(tokens.pop, reversed(indices_to_remove))][::-1], tokens
```

Test:

```py
tokens, indices_to_remove = gen(1_000_000)

%timeit f0(tokens, indices_to_remove)
134 ms ± 603 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%timeit f4(tokens, indices_to_remove)
111 ms ± 34.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%timeit f1(tokens, indices_to_remove)
76.9 ms ± 194 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Here is a benchmark to see the runtime differences over scale (length of tokens; note, the number of tokens to delete is always `~sqrt(n)`:

```py
import perfplot

perfplot.show(
    setup=gen,
    kernels=[f0, f1, f4, Kelly_1],
    n_range=[2**k for k in range(3, 20)],
    relative_to=1,
    xlabel='n elements',
    equality_check=lambda x, y: x == y,
)
```

[image]

We see something very interesting about `Kelly_1`: even though it does some extra steps (copy the initial list, to protect the argument, sort the set to make it a sorted list), this absolutely obliterates all other solutions, up to about 100K elements. After that, the time ramps up significantly. I need to understand why.

Tested with Python 3.9.0.

Comment: ok, modified for no more `numpy`. Conclusions unchanged.

Comment: Ah dangit, of course. Sorry.  I was thinking of my own solution, which does modify...

Comment: If the indices are sorted, popping seems faster with your test case: [try](https://tio.run/##jVNbasMwEPzXKfQXqzjBIRRKIFfoBYwRIl41otaj0iYklJ49lSw5aZvQ1uAPj3ZmZ7Rrd8KdNasn589n6a2mWuCOKu2sR6rCm0dSPrwwvdWEoH0FE@iGtnJ2nL@rjxmV1lNFlUk1L1AtedM06WUdUaZXWwgcLfeg7QEiMQBWWW0RhHYDVITGJ5MHMFVuwVidHXzHCGOE9CCpbAoYy352YetRsocBEPpkFrLLmkIyCmavwQuESZcqmSPcSHWj0jX1v4SMxV/EPODem8ldXcRLqsc/UxV6@6CFK8ULZ10dDw7gA/TVDZMz1rXr9XzZXbolpdvx8DSfOO57IvHexxVBpUHhtCTRtNgPyBPqqQjjMYGjgy1GsWdrgKQb49cFWY1BEigTKJs6xs7ZttadIit7bNfl8hMSVStW8ofYMGKySuX3Lmqsc14ZrDKRzinGLgvOjdDAea6IsypGVRidZhPpuQTI3UYchvClQoQA6b8objaFMi3elZh9sPP5Ew)

Comment: Ha! Your solution with `pop` looks like a wonderful idea. That's a native way of both altering the list and obtaining the items removed. I was thinking about how to do a single list comprehension (instead of my solution with two). But no cigar. List comprehensions are typically extremely fast. The reason @thefourtheye's solution is faster, despite using `list.append()`, is because there is only one pass.

Comment: Oh, ha, I just realized your solution also depends on the indices being sorted, otherwise your result has wrong order.

Comment: Actually for `deleted`, you should just iterate over the given indices. That's faster and supports unordered indices.

Comment: Also, since they care about the order, the input should really be a list, not a set. And the conversion to set should be included in the time.

Comment: The tio site uses old versions of python. With python 3.10.7, the pop version is three times slower.

Comment: @ekhumoro Three times slower instead of three times faster? That's very surprising. I wonder what results you'd get on your system with TIO's Python version. Anyway, my `Kelly_2` function should be much faster in this benchmark :-)

Comment: TBH, the timings on TIO seem completely bogus. I just tested with python-3.8 and 3.9, and the pop version is still much slower (by about 50%).

Comment: @ekhumoro Thanks for testing. I also tried on ideone (pop version takes twice as long, Py 3.7.3) and replit (pop version takes half as long, Py 3.8.12). Might be the most system-dependent thing I've ever seen in Python.

Comment: @KellyBundy: thx for your comment earlier that for `deleted`, you can just iterate over the indices (duh! Of course!) The result is `f1`, which is so far the fastest of the lot. Now, I have some different assumptions than you: I think the problem ought to be: `indices_to_remove`'s order is irrelevant (so it can be a set, thanks goodness), and the order of `deleted`, as well as the modified `tokens`, are both ordered as per the original.

Comment: Well, my "assumptions" are really their replies to my questions (in the comments under the question).

Comment: Actually, I stand corrected. Your version blows everything out of the water, at least for certain parameters.

Comment: re. assumptions: I question the precision of the answers you received to your questions. At the very least, the question should be amended to showcase what is desired if `indices_to_remove` is not monotonically increasing.

Comment: Thanks. Could you include `Kelly_2` as well? It was 10 times faster than `Kelly_1` in my testing (with your original benchmark, i.e., n=1e6).

Comment: Hmm, as I see those comments, they confirmed that `indices_to_remove` *is* monotonically increasing.

Comment: Why `Kelly_1` ramps up significantly at large n: With your test cases, it's O(n^1.5) whereas the other solutions are O(n).

Answer (score 1):

Sort the indices list in descending order. If you remove the biggest index first, it can't possibly affect the index of elements *earlier* in the sequence.

```
deleted_records = []
tokens = ['hi', 'what', 'is', 'there']
indices_to_remove = [2,3]
for index in sorted(indices_to_remove, reverse=True): 
    deleted_tokens.append(tokens[index])
    del tokens[index]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
deleted_records = []
tokens = ['hi', 'what', 'is', 'there']
del_tokens = tokens+[]
indices_to_remove = [2,3]
for index in indices_to_remove: 
    deleted_records.append(tokens[index])
    del_tokens[index]=''
del_tokens_real = []
for t in del_tokens:
    if t!='':
       del_tokens_real.append(t)
print(del_tokens_real)
print(deleted_records)
```

First replace records should delete with '' and then filter other records from it to get the output. Otherwise as the list size change during the delete issues can occur.

Answer (score 0):

Two solutions...

This one pops the values from back to front (relies on `indices_to_remove` being sorted):

```
def Kelly_1(tokens, indices_to_remove):
    return [*map(tokens.pop, reversed(indices_to_remove))][::-1], tokens
```

This one gets the requested values and then copies the other values into a separate list using slices. Supports `indices_to_remove` being unsorted. If it's sorted, the `sorted` call can be removed.

```
def Kelly_2(tokens, indices_to_remove):
    removed = [tokens[i] for i in indices_to_remove]
    retained = []
    start = 0
    for i in sorted(indices_to_remove):
        retained += tokens[start:i]
        start = i + 1
    retained += tokens[start:]
    return removed, retained
```

Comment: The performance of the second one depends heavily on the length of the indices list (and the disribution of its values).

Comment: @ekhumoro Both do. I pretty much wrote them targeting Pierre's benchmark and similarly sparse removals. And it's precisely the reason I didn't say anything about speed here, even though the second one is very fast in Pierre's benchmark. Usually I would, and usually I write benchmarks myself. A lot. I considered asking the OP for such details about the inputs, but I already had to ask twice just for the sortedness, so I didn't feel like it...

Comment: @ekhumoro How does it depend on the *distribution*? The first one does, but the second one?

Comment: @ekhumoro `itemgetter` seems faster still, see results in the [Output](https://tio.run/##XZHdasMwDIXv/RS6KbFDyBJKyxjkSUoJbqN2gvgHW73Y02e2k2xjNzbSOdb5hP0Xfzp7fPdhWR7BGWAySAxkvAsMAT1qFiIivzwMUFWVKLag7ZSuzRa18TOuivMYNLuwa09kYjQN5DMVjGE1pjqwc3P8H6ZT0EyRZQp5ouy7uj4rJchOdMeYxDVO6gb6ruuUeN5btPqWWkpkQnF3UzHm4qIvdIVHBgKysE25iktttJe6HceNcBybXVW7/AO/skmt/noK5O9ast6l5CskbeRAXqo2@pl4JosxIYoMM2aYdcGj@hBQCDN37hf@3ATgtIYhKzeArDRQvqMB@zI3DMNpxxv6Til4g1N56QNZltXhOMErQgUHkFz3eE4r5ClK7Ba1LN8) section.

Comment: Yeah, I discounted any approach that requires imports. Anyway, the differences between the other approaches don't seem statistically significant, so it's probably best to just stick with what's most readable.